# Easy way to programmatically change all font types and sizes in all figures in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am generating a number of plots in MATLAB. The axis labels and the tick labels are currently too small when included in my final document. I would like to change the font size for both axis labels and tick labels while also setting a new default typeface. I have tried the `FontSize` and `FontName` name value pair but strangely see no effect on the exported .eps files; also this method is somewhat impractical because I am generating a large number of plots.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can have a look at [exportfig](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2010/05/28/creating-and-exporting-publication-quality-graphics/) or this [blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/12/11/making-pretty-graphs/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `findobj` to programmatically edit all figures.
For example:

```
ah = findobj(,'Type','axes'); % get all axes
set(ah,'FontSize',Whatever); %this will change all the tick labels
for m=1:numel(ah) % go over all axes
  xlabel_handle = get(ah(m),'xlabel');
  set(xlabel_handle,'FontSize',Whatever); % this will change only the label
  %repeat for other labels if you wish
end
```