# Setting Fontsizes for all plots that will be generated

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have a script genereating and saving multiple plots. Now I want to define a set of properties for all the plots that are going to be generated. Properties I'm going to set are for example `'FontSize'`,`'XTick'` or `'XTickLabel'`. Of course I could just go ahead and set those properties for each figure individually, but since I want all of them to look pretty much the same, I was wondering if there isn't a easier way of doing it.
I found this with the searchfunction:
[Easy way to programmatically change all font types and sizes in all figures in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29716854/easy-way-to-programmatically-change-all-font-types-and-sizes-in-all-figures-in-m)
The problem with this is, that it sets the properties, after i have already used the `print`-command on each of the plots and so they have been saved without the properties already.

Comment: Does [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32655648/2605073) help?

Comment: Yes, it does, thank you! Shall I delete this as duplicate?

Comment: there is no difference between using `0` and `groot`, right?!

Comment: no, there is no difference. I mark it as duplicate